# I am not seeing the effect of Tailwind CSS on my react-Django code. I followed the https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

Here is the folder structure -[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5mMg.png)

I tried to follow the official documentation on how to install the Tailwiind css.

```
module.exports = {
plugins: {
 tailwindcss: {},
 autoprefixer: {},
},
}
```

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

```
--index.css--
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: What were you expecting that doesn't work right now? Please provide more information and code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am trying to style using Tailwindcss. I had a react-django working app and I installed the tailwindcss by following the official documentation after I make sure the reac-django app was working.

Comment: You might try to add what is in your `index.css` to your `App.css`.  Although it is a guessing based in the info you provided. Do you get errors?